# JSP - Scope attribute name same as EL implicit object

Tags: jsp, el

Can you please explain me the behavior ? I am setting a request attribute in a servlet and reading it in the JSP .

1) Dispatcher servlet code :

```
request.setAttribute("someName", someObject);
```

Naturally , I can read it in JSP as `${someName}`

2) But if I set the attribute name same as some EL implicit object name, like

```
request.setAttribute("requestScope", someObject);
```

Then I have to read it as `${requestScope.requestScope}` !

Why the container is able to map the attribute in case#1 directly but in case the attribute name itself is an EL implicit object name we need to nest the reference like `${requestScope.requestScope}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL will first check if the given variable name is one of the reserved (implicit) variable names and then use it as per the specification. If not, like as in `${someName}`, then EL will automatically search for an attribute with exactly that name in respectively page, request, session and application scope.

You seem to expect that this works the other way round, i.e. first the attribute and then the implicit objects. This is not true. It would otherwise completely break the working of implicit EL objects.